# Django URL Regex for an "Address"

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I'm trying to write a url regex in my urls.py for a json query that will take a url like such:

```
http://localhost:8000/structures/hydrants/3/json?address=100+Washington+Road,+Sacramento,+CA
```

and direct that to a view as such:

```
def hydrant_json(request, hydrant_address):
    hydrant = Hydrant.objects.filter(address = hydrant_address)
    data = [hydrant.json()]
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

Address is defined as such:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "addresses"
    street_num = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def json(self):
        fields = ('street_num', 'street', 'city', 'state')
        return {
            'street_num': str(self.street_num),
            'street': str(self.street),
            'city': str(self.city),
            'state': str(self.state)
        }
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.street_num) + ' ' + self.street + ', ' + self.city + ', ' + self.state
```

and hydrant.json() works, everything is dandy on the view side.  I just want the regex to take in an exact address in the format shown above, fit into a query URL.

Thanks!

Comment: Try this regex `[\w\+,]+` this regex will allow just extra `_` also. To be strict `[a-zA-Z0-9,\+]+`

Comment: ObXKCD: http://xkcd.com/208/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
r'(?<address>^\d{1,5}\s[a-zA-z\s]+,\s[a-zA-z]+,\s[A-Z]{,2}$)'
```

This is about as strict as it gets.

Basically what it does is:

- makes sure it starts with a number
- makes sure the the number is max 5 digits long(not sure who long this can go to, adjust{1,5} if needed
- makes sure comma, space and street name follows
- makes sure comma, space and city name follows
- makes sure comma, state follows and it ends with state